# When seaching for "views:xxxxx" why don't all the questions that satisfy that show?

Tags: bug

I searched for ["views:20000"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A20000&submit=search) but it did not return all of the questions that fit that criteria, as shown by a search for ["views:19000"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A19000&submit=search) (which also doesn't return all questions). Why does this happen?